# Curl not recognized

Tags: c#, curl

I cannot find the right answer to this already asked question so I decided to ask it again. I cannot get curl to work when calling it from a program. I get "curl is not recognized as an internal or external command". I have installed curl into the \Windows\System32\ folder, as well as set the environmental variable path. I have installed the cert and have renamed it to curl-ca-bundle.cert. Curl works when I open a command prompt and run it manually but not from my program. The only answers I can find is the guy who keeps copying how to install curl in 4 steps but that doesn't pertain to me. Any help would be great.
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the command in your program?  Also it could be a permissions issue. I'm not familiar with Windows that well so not sure if that would result in a different error if it was related to permissions.

Comment: "Curl works when I open a command prompt and run it manually but not from my program" -- you have to show us that c# code if you want any help.

Comment: Yes I have tried using the full path and it gives me the same error. I will post my code shortly.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable contains *directory paths* not files. You just created serious problems for your machine, including the *inability* to locate the proper file. Plus, you are running inside the wrong folder - you are inside the 32-bit clone of `system32`. Please fix your environment varialbe **REMOVE** curl from `system32` and install it in a *PROPER* folder, outside the system folder. Then try again

Comment: Post the *code* not the screenshot. But first, fix your machine. You may run into problems when you reboot if you leave the executable inside `PATH`. Please reverse anything you did trying to force execution of `curl`

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos that worked. I didnt' realize you weren't suppose to put the file in the path or the environmental variable. The advice I found online seemed to state that that was the proper way of doing it, as well as putting it inside the System32 folder instead of just the Windows folder. Thanks again.

Comment: @rusty the `PATH` variable is used to store *folders* that should be searched to find an executalbe file. As for such advices, there are memes out there about "Found it on the Internet", especially when the OS screams at you and *requires* administration priviledges before copying anything inside `System32`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Panagiotis Kanavos was able to answer my question in the comments above.

I replaced the PATH variable with just the PATH only. I also installed cURL outside the system32 folder like suggested. Doing this solved my issues.

Comment: please update this "answer" to include the steps you selected from the running conversation above to solve your problem. As is, the answer doesn't answer your problem in the form expected on StackOverflow. OK? ;-) Glad you got a solution, getting curl to work in a PITA, ain't it ;-) (Will reverse my downvote if/when you improve your answer). Good luck.